# Concept of parallelism in analytic terms

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

Below I cited a passage from *Apostol's Calculus*. I don't understand how to use the identity to show that two lines with equal slopes are parallel.

> Concepts such as perpendicularity and parallelism can be explained
>   rather simply in analytic terms making use of slopes of lines. For
>   example, from the trigonometric identity
>
> $$tan(\alpha - \beta) = \frac{tan(\alpha) - tan(\beta)}{1 + tan(\alpha)tan(\beta)}$$
>
> it follows that two nonvertical lines with the same slope are
>   parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the two nonvertical lines have the same slope, then

(1) they have the same angle of inclination (assuming that one is α and the other is β).

---- This means $\alpha = \beta$ and hence they  are parallel [corresponding angles].

---- Also α = β implies tan (α - β) = 0 [the LHS]

(2) same slope implies  tan α = tan β.

---- Thus , tan α - tan β = 0 [the RHS]